# Win8 consent.exe "File system error -1073741819"

Tags: windows-8, uac

consent.exe ([UAC]) is failing for me every time I try to install a program or driver, or disable UAC;

```
Faulting application name: consent.exe, version: 6.2.9200.16384, time stamp: 0x50108159
Faulting module name: ntdll.dll, version: 6.2.9200.16420, time stamp: 0x505ab405
Exception code: 0xc0000005
Fault offset: 0x0000000000005552
Faulting process ID: 0x2bbc
Faulting application start time: 0x01ce184623ef0458
Faulting application path: C:\WINDOWS\system32\consent.exe
Faulting module path: C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\ntdll.dll
Report ID: 6296dc08-8439-11e2-be7f-bc5ff40e81d2
Faulting package full name: 
Faulting package-relative application ID:
```

The popup windows states "File system error -1073741819", so it might be a filesystem error or maybe registry error?  Can I reset UAC somehow?

I have been removed a lot of installer program, ran windows repair and checked the drive, I havent found anything with this.

Comment: Exactly how did you "check the drive"? Faults in the NTDLL.DLL usually point to bad drivers or hardware. Check out Microsoft's [Driver Verifier](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-ca/library/windows/hardware/ff545448) if you want to try and detect which driver is crashing (warning: not for the faint of heart).

Comment: I've seen some really goofy problems for this with sound codecs. consent.exe plays a sound when it pops up, and if you have a bad audio driver, consent crashes. Try booting into safe mode and turning off your audio drivers.

Comment: @vcjones uninstalled all the drivers, still the same problem. Then I turned off all notifications, this allowed me to diable UAC.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems to help

1. Settings set system sounds - selected all off
2. Disabled UAC
3. Uninstalled all **sound** drivers
4. reboot
5. reinstalled sound drivers
6. enabled UAC again